# Controls overlap when trying to position programmatically using relative layout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a fragment. In the fragment I plan to place a text view next to it a Spinner control. I tried using this code. However Spinner always is placed over textview to the left of the screen. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

Code:

```
public class FragmentTest extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.ll2, null);
    RelativeLayout lref = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll2ll);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(lref.getLayoutParams());

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setId(1);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp); 
    tv.setText("My ");


    rl.addView(tv, lp);

    Spinner s = new Spinner(getActivity());
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());
    s.setId(2);
    String currencyData[] = {"USD",
            "EUR","INR"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<Object> currencyAdapter; currencyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencyData);
    currencyAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(currencyAdapter);

    rl.addView(s,lp);
    return rl;
}
}
```

XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2ll"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(lref.getLayoutParams());

your problem is this, you can't use the same layout parameters for adding all the layouts and modifying the lp.
because the lp is used after you have initialized all the layouts, that means you are using same parameters for all the layouts spinner and textview both.

try using different layout parameters for all the layouts

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lptextview

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpspinner

for all of them

if your problem is solved mark my answser as correct

Answer (score 2):

When a view is inflated from a XML you will not get the `LayoutParams` properly. Try using `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`